# MySQL Scheduled event not running on Pi4

Tags: mysql

Have 2 events scheduled on MySQL running on my Pi4, set as recurring neither has ever executed. They are both designed to truncate records older than xxx in two separate tables.

Server type: MariaDB

Server version: 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 - Raspbian 10

PHP version: 7.3.19-1~deb10u1

Have event scheduler set to always start and have verified that it is running via check.  Also show process list verifies that it is running.  Results of show processlist is:

6
event_scheduler
localhost
NULL
Daemon
107784
Waiting for next activation
NULL
0.000

Checked that the event_scheduler user has proper global permissions to Select, Update, Insert, and Delete.

The event is Enabled and set to recurring.

Have also verified proper SQL via query simulation which would result in proper record deletion, and have checked that the event_scheduler user has the proper permissions for the tables that I am attempting to delete records from.  Have done exhaustive reading, but still no luck.  Any ideas welcome and appreciated!

Comment: Just a wild guess: clock OK?  You've got ntp running or ntpdate is run on boot?

Comment: Gerard, I know that the Pi is properly set up to sync the time service, and one of the data columns in both tables that the events are to be actioning against have an accurate timestamp field, so yes...I believe that all NTP setup is correct.  Also the output of processlist does show huge duration for the event_scheduler time is transpiring while waiting for next job (activation).  Leads me to believe that this is not the issue, but thank you!

Comment: Can you add the "show events" & "show create events" ?

Comment: As I am a new stackoverflow user I am not allowed to upload pictures.  :(

Comment: However the show events SQL query against one of the tables that I am attempting to truncate shows a result of  " MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)"

Comment: I am using the PHP myAdmin as the UI and can accurately see the scheduled events, event scheduler set to on, scheduled event set to active and recurring...etc.

Comment: No pictures, text please!

Comment: Results of show events ran against the table that I am trying to truncate:     MySQL returned an empty result set

Comment: Results of show events does list the two events that I have created.  db-mysql, name-name of my event, definer-my user as I was logged on when creating the event, time zone-SYSTEM, Execute at-NULL, Interval Value-15, Interval Field-Minute, Starts-2020-11-19, Ends-Null, Status-Enabled, Originator-1, character set client-utf8mb4, collation_connection-utf8mb4_unicode_ci, Database Collation-utf8mb4_general_ci

Comment: SHOW CREATE EVENT Truncate_Exterior_Climate  returns the following:      Event
sql_mode
time_zone
Create Event
character_set_client
collation_connection
Database Collation
Truncate_Exterior_Climate
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_...
SYSTEM
CREATE DEFINER=`PhpJohnG`@`localhost` EVENT `Trunc...
utf8mb4
utf8mb4_unicode_ci
utf8mb4_general_ci

Comment: The sql within the event is:  DELETE FROM exterior_climate WHERE Timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 9 DAY    Which I have verified is properly formatted and when simulating the query would indeed execute

Comment: You could have edited your question, that would have been easier to read.  The "..." are not really informative.  I would have liked to see the full "create event". In the mean time, did you check MariaDB's error log?

Comment: To make it easer to locate a possible error, add a comment:  " DELETE FROM exterior_climate /* John Gibson was Here! */ WHERE Timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 9 DAY"

Comment: your "show events"  does not show "type: recurring". Any idea?

Comment: Here is the result from the edited event run simulated:    `SQL query:
DELETE FROM exterior_climate /* John Gibson was Here! */ WHERE Timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 9 DAY
Matched rows: 62622`

Comment: I am trying to get readable feedback into this conversation, but as I am running all SQL statements from within PHPMyAdmin, it is difficult to copy and paste the results.  This said when I run show events, the two scheduled events do show that they are set as recurring with the proper execution interval

Comment: OK...I found the error log, there are errors associated with the event  `2021-01-20 10:56:33 46 [Note] Event Scheduler: [PhpJohnG@localhost][mysql.Truncate_Exterior_Climate] At line 1 in mysql.Truncate_Exterior_Climate
2021-01-20 10:56:33 46 [Note] Event Scheduler: [PhpJohnG@localhost].[mysql.Truncate_Exterior_Climate] event execution failed.`

Comment: Looks like the event is pointing to the incorrect db...I will attempt to fix

Comment: SOLVED:  The SQL statement needed to be modified to include the database being actioned against.  When creating the event apparently the default db is the mysql db and since I had created a new db and tables the query needs to be  `dbname.tablename`.  Thank you so much for leading me to the error log.  This is my first work with any sql db, so did not know where to go.

Comment: I like to teach a man to fish.